# Bluetooth is unstable in 14.04

Tags: bluetooth, 14.04

I use a filco bluetooth keyboard and a logitech bluetooth mouse on my Thinkpad T540p with 14.04 LTS (the bluetooth adapter is Intel Dual Band Wireless 7260AC). They can
be connected successfully. However, the connection seems to be quite unstable. In many case, after I use them for a while, the system disconnects my devices and then automatically reconnect them, thus I have to wait for about 10s for them to work again. In some other case, the software reports "the battery of your devices is low (0%)" and then I have to restart the bluetooth services in order to make my devices work again.

Comment: This is really a bug report, not a question.